# JavaScript graph trend lines(zone back color) and upside down y axis

Tags: javascript, graph, trendline

I need a cross browser / platform two series line graph/chart. We used to have fusionchart but due to some known limitation we want to use something like jqplot.

The target is close to the attached image, except for 1 thing: the y series values should be upside down (not from 110 to -10, but from -10 to 110). I could not figure out how to do it in jqplot.

To sum up, we need:

- two series line chart
- y series from smallest value to largest value
  (**no idea**)
- trend line with (zone background color), with labels
  like the "Severe Loss", "Moderate Loss" and "Mild Loss" on the right.
  (**no idea**)

It doesn't matter which JavaScript graph to use, as long as it can meet the above 3 requirements

[image: sample graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I finally figure out how by using [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/).

- two series line chart
- y series from smallest value to largest value (**with transform and inverseTransform function of yaxis**)
- trend line with (zone background color), with labels like the "Severe
  Loss", "Moderate Loss" and "Mild Loss" on the right. (**with markings, altough there is no label for marking, but I could try to hack it**)